# Random probability

Tags: probability

So the story is my friend was playing Runescape and he was trying to get an item drop that had a ${1\over 128}$ drop rate so on average every $128$ monsters he slays one of the items will drop.he asked me how many does he have to kill in order to get the item so I came up with the answer -
The probability of getting at least $1$ of item would be $\int_0^a{1\over 128}e^{-x\over 128}dx$ where $a$ is the amount of monsters you've killed. The way I got to this conclusion was a lot of guessing and feeling in the seat of my pants. Could someone enlighten me of this is correct?

Comment: Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting information.  I don't quite follow your reasoning for your answer.  I would describe it as a binomial distribution instead: The chance of no drops after $n$ kills would be $(\frac{127}{128})^n$.  The chance of at least one drop is one minus that.  This is of course assuming that there is no "pity timer" and drop chances are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that:

1. Each monster killed results in either $0$ or $1$ items dropping.
2. The number of items dropped for any given kill is independent of the outcome of any other kills.
3. The probability that any given kill results in an item dropping is $p = 1/128$.

Then, the random number $X$ of items dropped after $n$ kills is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p = 1/128$, with probability mass function $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n;$$ namely, the probability of obtaining exactly $x$ items in $n$ drops is given by the formula above.  The probability that, after $n$ kills, at least one item is dropped, is simply $$\Pr[X > 0] = 1 - \Pr[X = 0] = 1 - \binom{n}{0} p^0 (1-p)^{n-0} = 1 - (1-p)^n.$$

In a different vein, suppose we are not interested in the number of items dropped for a fixed number of kills, but rather, the random number of kills $Y$ needed until we observe the first drop.  This is characterized by a **geometric** distribution:  $$\Pr[Y = y] = p(1-p)^{y-1}, \quad y = 1, 2, \ldots.$$  That is to say, with probability $p$, only $Y = 1$ kill is needed; with probability $p(1-p)$, exactly $Y = 2$ kills are needed; and so forth.

The expected number of kills needed to observe the first drop is of course $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = 1/p.$$  But because the outcome of each kill is independent, this is certainly no guarantee that after any fixed number of kills, that we would observe at least one item drop.  This is like flipping a coin:  the outcomes of previous flips do not influence future ones.  So, just because the expected number of kills needed is $128$, that does not mean that after $128$ kills, you *should* have one item.  Indeed, the above formula tells us that, for any $y$, there is a strictly positive probability that more than $y$ kills are needed to observe the first item drop.  (Exercise:  what is this probability; i.e., what is $\Pr[Y > y]$?)

A little thought should convince you that, as a result, we cannot ensure with $100\%$ certainty that there is some number of kills that guarantees an item drop.  We can only say, for example, that with probability $\psi < 1$, $Y$ kills are needed to obtain the first item drop.  If you choose a suitably large $\psi$, say, $\psi = 0.95$, then you can calculate (using the formula you obtained in the exercise above) the number of kills you would need to be $95\%$ sure of getting at least one item.  You can even choose $\psi = 0.999$, and that would give you the number of kills needed to be $99.9\%$ sure of getting at least one item.  But if you tried to plug in $\psi = 1$, what happens to the number of kills needed?

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable assumption is that the number of items dropped follows a Poisson distribution with $\lambda = a/128$, where $a$ is the number of monsters killed.  Then the probability that at least one item is dropped is $$1-e^{-\lambda}$$